# Не читаемая кириллица при импорте из config.ini python

Tags: python, кодировка, кириллица, config

При импорте из файла config.ini списка, кириллица становиться такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

encode И decode в utf-8 не помогают

Код commands.ini

```
[comm]
choose="выбрать"
```

Код main.py

```
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read("settings.ini")
cfg.read("commands.ini")

alias = [cfg["comm"]["choose"]]


#### Discord import ###
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=cfg["MixBot"]["prefix"]+" ") #инициализируем бота с префиксом из конфига


#### Commands ####
@bot.command(helpinfo='Выбирает случайное значение из указанных через пробел', aliases=[alias[0]])
async def choose(ctx, *choices: str):
    print(alias[0])
    await ctx.send("Думаю это " + (random.choice(choices)))
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы читаете файл.

Comment: добавил код с выделением

Comment: А в какой кодировке ini файл сам?

Comment: в utf-8  # commands.ini
[comm]
choose="выбрать"

Comment: @GriteLine, во-первых добавьте код текстом, во-вторых приведенного фрагмента недостаточно - не понятно что такое cfg, откуда оно взялось.

Comment: @insolor сделал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас файлы конфигурации содержат текст в кодировке utf-8. При чтении из файла нужно указать кодировку:

```
config.read("settings.ini", encoding="utf-8")
config.read("commands.ini", encoding="utf-8")
```

Документация: [ConfigParser, метод read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример рабочего кода, никаких конфликтов с кириллицей:

```
import configparser
def wr():
    # запишет что-нибудь в конфиг
    cfg=configparser.ConfigParser()
    cfg.add_section('comm')
    cfg.set('comm', 'choose', 'вырбать')
    with open('myConfig.ini', 'w') as cf:
        cfg.write(cf)
def rd():
    # прочитаем конфиг
    cfg=configparser.ConfigParser()
    cfg.read('myConfig.ini')
    alias = cfg.get('comm', 'choose')
    return alias

wr()
print(rd())
```